# Make symmetric matrix from vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, toeplitz

I have to convert the vector into matrix

```
x<-c(1:5)
mat<-matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    if (i==j) {
      mat[i,j]<-x[3]
    } else 
      if (i < j) { ##for upper diagonal
        mat[i,j]<-x[j]
      }
  }
}
```

The resultning matrix shall be

```
    [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1      2    3
[2,] 4      1    2
[3,] 5      4    1
```

I know that it is a kind of toeplitz matrix and there are packages available in R, but i have to do that with nested for loops.

Comment: How is this a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be done with `toeplitz` and the function is from `base R` i.e. no packages are needed

```
 `diag<-`(toeplitz(x)[-(2:3), 1:3], 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    1    2
[3,]    5    4    1
```

---

Regarding the nested loop, an option is

```
x <- c(1:5)
mat <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    if (i==j) {
      mat[i,j]<-x[1]
    } else if (i > j) { 
         if((i + j) < length(x)){
            mat[i,j] <- x[(i + j + 1)]
         } else {
            mat[i, j] <- x[(i + j) - 1]
         }  
      } else {
          if((i + j) < length(x)) {
           mat[i, j] <- x[j]
          } else {
            mat[i, j] <- x[i]
          }
              }
  }
}
```

-output

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    1    2
[3,]    5    4    1
```

Comment: thanks for quick and correct response.